# Parsing specific rows in a tab-separated file in python

Tags: python, string-parsing

I have a tab-separated file with no format. The file format is just listed as FILE. When I open it with a text editor, it looks like:

```
Job Wanted_VERB "_. 2000    1   1
Job Wanted_VERB "_. 2001    1   1
Job Wanted_VERB "_. 2002    5   5
Job Wanted_VERB "_. 2004    2   2
Job Wanted_VERB "_. 2005    2   2
Job Wanted_VERB "_. 2006    2   2
Job Wanted_VERB "_. 2007    1   1
Job Well Done   1917    1   1
Job Well Done   1930    3   2
Job Well Done   1937    1   1
Job Well Done   1940    5   4
Job Well Done   1941    3   3
Job Well Done   1942    1   1
Job Well Done   1943    2   2
Job Well Done   1944    1   1
Job Well Done   1945    1   1
Job Well Done   1946    3   3
Job Well Done   1948    1   1
Job Well Done   1949    4   4
Job Well Done   1950    1   1
Job Well Done   1951    3   2
Job Well Done   1952    6   4
Job Well Done   1953    9   5
Job Well Done   1954    6   4
Job Well Done   1955    5   5
....
....
```

where the first three columns are 3 gram sentence and the rest are related to the word frequency.

It is a huge file, so I just want to parse the part that only contains the 3 gram word that I am looking for. For example, from the table above, I would like to parse only the `Job Well Done` part.

```
Job Well Done   1917    1   1
Job Well Done   1930    3   2
Job Well Done   1937    1   1
Job Well Done   1940    5   4
Job Well Done   1941    3   3
Job Well Done   1942    1   1
Job Well Done   1943    2   2
Job Well Done   1944    1   1
Job Well Done   1945    1   1
Job Well Done   1946    3   3
Job Well Done   1948    1   1
Job Well Done   1949    4   4
Job Well Done   1950    1   1
Job Well Done   1951    3   2
Job Well Done   1952    6   4
Job Well Done   1953    9   5
Job Well Done   1954    6   4
Job Well Done   1955    5   5
```

I am currently doing this to parse the whole file and put it into a list:

```
with open(file, 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as input:
    z = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in input]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, add startswith as an if statement, like this:

```
with open(file, 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as input:
    z = [line.strip().split("\t") for line in f if line.startswith("Job Well Done")]
```

Comment: It gives me an error: ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @Dawn17 I thought you said that you where reading the file already.

Comment: @Dawn17 Sorry I am confused, hopefully someone else can help you better.